# When optimizing a table is there a way to tell how long it is "locked" for?

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

When running the optimize table command in MySQL, is there anyway to see how long the table is actually "locked for"? In the notes for optimize table command it just says it is locked for for a brief time.

So my question is, is there a script or command that you can run at the same time as the optimize command to find out how long the table was down for?

Comment: You may try to scan `performance_schema.data_locks` table (from event scheduler, for example, each second) for the records relative to your table (and save them into some table for future analysis).

Comment: When i try to run "performance_schema.data_locks", it says that data_locks doesn't exist.

Comment: Oops... `metadata_locks`.

Comment: im afraid i get the same error :(

Comment: ??? you get the error that the table not exists?

Comment: Yes is that bad?

Comment: I think that your MySQL account have no enough privileges for accessing PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA database... it is strange. Check does it is listed in `SHOW DATABASES;`?

Comment: it does not show in listed databases and its not a privilege issue

Comment: Don't use `OPTIMIZE TABLE`; it is almost never needed.  If you have a case where it is useful, please describe it so we can discuss the issue, and possibly some workarounds.